# Use jquery.sumoselect with JSF

Tags: jquery, jsf, multi-select, sumoselect.js

I want to use [jquery.sumoselect](https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/) with JSF. However I am not able. I am trying the following:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="jquery.sumoselect" name="css/sumoselect.css" />
<h:outputScript library="jquery.sumoselect" name="js/jquery.sumoselect.js" />
<script>
  $('.sumoselect').SumoSelect();
</script>
...

<h:form>
  ...
  <h:selectManyListbox id="language" value="#{viewController.languageList}" styleClass="sumoselect">
    <f:selectItems value="#{applicationStartupController.languageList}" var="language" itemValue="#{language.code}" itemLabel="#{language.description}" />
  </h:selectManyListbox>
  ...
</h:form>
```

However all I get is the following image:

[image: Image 1]

Instead of something similar to:

[image: Image 2]

Any idea of what's happening? I am sure that the css and js files are charging correctly.

Comment: Without going into specifics, can you try this `<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sumoselect').SumoSelect();
});

</script>`

Comment: Are you implying that the same approach works fine with "plain" HTML instead of with JSF-generated HTML output? The code posted so far suggests that it would just fail the same way.

Comment: mike123, it still doesn't work with your script

Comment: BalusC, it doesn't work with the plain HTML, I don't know why

Comment: Hint: in case you have a basic HTML/jQuery problem, in order to increase chance in getting answers/duplicates from HTML/jQuery experts, you'd better reframe the question to show a HTML based MCVE instead of a JSF based one as the average jQuery developer usually can't tell from top of head how the JSF-generated HTML output looks like. Once you get the answer, just alter JSF source code accordingly that it generates exactly the desired/answered HTML output.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems ok, except that you should probably run the `SumoSelect()` after the document is ready:

```
<h:head>
    <title>Sumo</title>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="sumoselect.css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery.sumoselect.min.js"/>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <h:selectManyListbox styleClass="test">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Item 1" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Item 2" />   
        <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Item 3" />   
    </h:selectManyListbox>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.test').SumoSelect({okCancelInMulti:true, selectAll:true });
        });
    </script>
</h:body>
```